# What distribution is this? (and how to simulate a sample from it in R)

Tags: r, distributions, sample

This is the information given: 10% of the population is colour blind. Let $X$ be the number of colour-blind people in a sample of 20.

The distribution is $X \sim Poisson(20, 2)$ - is this correct?

Then it asks to simulate a sample of size $N = 1500$ from distribution of $X$.

Comment: Is it a homework? If so please use `self-study` tag and read the [tag:self-study] Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

In your case,

$X \sim Binomial(20,0.1)$

And you simulate by r code

```
rbinom(1500,20,0.1)
```

Comment: Please comment also on *why* this is a correct answer and what is wrong with Poisson in here. Without this information OP cannot learn anything from it.